# Has any Advaita Acharya or scholar resolved/answered/refuted Sapta Vidha Anupapatti?

Tags: philosophy, advaita

As, I've mentioned in [previous question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21529/277), Sapta Vidha Aupapatti, also called seven untenables are said to be an objection raised against the concept of Avidya of Advaita Vedanta.

I want to know has any Advaita Acharya or scholar resolved/answered/refuted those seven untenables?

Answer (score 4):

These are the 7 charges (*anupapatti*) that Ramanuja leveled against the theory of Maya. They are *ashrayanpapatti*, *tirodhananupapatti*, *svarupanupapatti*, *anirvachaniyatvanupapatti*, *pramananupapatti*, *nivartakanupapatti*, and *nivrtyanupapatti*. Prof. Chandradhar Sharma explains and refutes the 7 charges in his book

> [*A Critical Survey of Indian Philosophy*,](https://ia800804.us.archive.org/25/items/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey/Indian-Philosophy-A-Critical-Survey.pdf)

pp 358-361, Chapter 18, Section XV.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you provide reference link to that book?

Comment: Not available on internet. Can buy from here - http://www.mlbd.com/

Comment: @Pandya You can download pdf
 [here](https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey) .